# Is there a companion to the Form.onShow() method I can use when a Form is hidden?

Tags: codenameone

On some of my Forms, I register a sensor listener when I open the form, using the onShow() method. I want to deregister those listeners when I go to a different Form.

I found the onShow() method for anything I need to do when a Form is shown, but I don't see an onHide() method or any method I can use for a Form to clean up after itself. I could put the cleanup code in the navigation commands, but they really belong to the Form. Is there a method I can use that I overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't need to be aware of exiting a Form unless you are in a GUI builder application where navigation might be implicit. Since you always call `newForm.show()` implementing logic required for exit can be done there.

However, you can always override `deinitilize()` to do this. Notice it might be invoked when you are showing a `Dialog` so `initComponent()` might be a better counterpart than `onShow()`.

Notice that this only applies to the visual aspect of showing a `Form`. You will also need to implement logic in your `stop()` method that is invoked when your app is minimized and in the `start()` method which is invoked when the app is restored (both in the main class of your app).

Comment: It's true that you don't _normally_ need to be aware of exiting a 'Form'. Since I'm deregistering a listener to a native sensor, mine is a special case. The 'newForm.show()' method is a lousy place to do it, since that may not be how the form get hidden. In object-oriented thinking, the Form owns the responsibility of registering/deregistering the listener, so the best place to put this code would be a 'Form.onHide()' method that's certain to get called when the form gets hidden. (I already have code in my 'start()' and 'stop()' methods that defer to my start() and stop() methods in my forms.)

Comment: Did you notice he suggested `deinitialize()`/`initComponent()` both of which you can also do per component?

Comment: Actually, dinitialize() might work. I'll give it a shot.